# A cubic graph has a cutpoint if and only if it has a bridge

Tags: graph-theory

I proved the first part (it has a bridge => it has a cutpoint) but can you help me with the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $G$ be a cubic graph, and suppose that the vertex $u$ is a cut vertex. Let $v_1,v_2$, and $v_3$ be the neighbors of $u$ in $G$.

- Show that every vertex of $G-u$ is in the same component of $G-u$ as at least one of the vertices $v_1,v_2$, and $v_3$. Conclude that $v_1,v_2$, and $v_3$ cannot all be in the same component of $G-u$.

Without loss of generality assume that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are in different components of $G-u$.

- Show that if $\{u,v_1\}$ is not a bridge in $G$, then $v_3$ is the same component as $v_1$ in $G-u$.
- Similarly, if $\{u,v_2\}$ is not a bridge in $G$, then $v_3$ is the same component as $v_2$ in $G-u$.
- Conclude that at least one of the edges $\{u,v_1\}$ and $\{u,v_2\}$ must be a bridge in $G$.